# Make sure Type instance represents a type assignable from certain class

Tags: java, c#, types, extends

I'm primarily a Java programmer, so this would be one of those "what is this thing from Java equivalent to in C#" questions. So, in Java, you can restrain a Class type argument **at compile time** to extend a certain super-class, like so:

```
public <T extends BaseClass> void foo(Class<T> type) {
    ...
}
```

and even

```
public <T extends BaseClass> T foo(Class<T> type) {
    ...
}
```

You can even chain multiple interfaces:

```
public <T extends BaseClass & BaseInterface1 & BaseInterface2> void foo(Class<T> type) {
    ...
}
```

How is this done in C#? I know you can use "where T : BaseClass", but this is only applicable when you have an instance T. What about when you only have a Type instance?

EDIT:

For explanation, here is what I would like to do:

ASSEMBLY #1 (base.dll):

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    abstract void Foo();
}
```

ASSEMBLY #2 (sub1.dll, references base.dll):

```
class SubClass1 : BaseClass {
    void Foo() {
        // some code
    }
}
```

ASSEMBLY #3 (sub2.dll, references base.dll):

```
class SubClass2 : BaseClass {
    void Foo() {
        // some other code
    }
}
```

ASSEMBLY #4 (main.dll, references base.dll):

```
class BaseClassUtil {
    static void CallFoo(Type<T> type) where T : BaseClass {
        T instance = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        instance.Foo();
    }
}

public static void Main(String[] args) {
    // Here I use 'args' to get a class type,
    // possibly loading it dynamically from a DLL

    Type<? : BaseClass> type = LoadFromDll(args); // Loaded from DLL

    BaseClassUtil.CallFoo(type);
}
```

So, in this example, I don't care what class the 'type' variable represents, as long as it is derived from BaseClass, so once I create an instance, can call Foo().

The parts that are not vaild C# code (but rather some Java mockup) are the "generic" Type classes: Type<T> and Type<? : BaseClass>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to enforce at compile time that a `Type` be assignable to a generic type. If I understand correctly, what you want is:

```
 void Foo<T>(Type type) { ... } //compile time error if an instace typed `type` is not assignable to `T`.
```

Which means:

```
 void Foo<IFormattable>(typeof(string)); //ok
 void Foo<IDisposable>(typeof(string)); //compile time error
```

Evidently at runtime it is trival, but the language has no support for this at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understood you are talking about [**generic type constraint**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx)

```
public void Foo<T>(Type type) where T:BaseClass, BaseInterface1, BaseInterface2
{
    //your code
}
```

Here another article:[**Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

> When you define a generic class, you can apply restrictions to the
>   kinds of types that client code can use for type arguments when it
>   instantiates your class. If client code tries to instantiate your
>   class by using a type that is not allowed by a constraint, the result
>   is a compile-time error.

**EDIT:**

Here your example. Now if you try to call `BaseClassUtil.CallFoo<T>` with something different from BaseClass and his derived classes you will receive an compile error. Here [**full example in dotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hpEgYp). So the tricky part is the restriction of your class should happen in the Util class

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //so your LoadFromDll method should return Type. Type doesn't have generic implementation !
        Type type = typeof(SubClass1);

        BaseClassUtil.CallFoo<BaseClass>(type);

        Type type2 = typeof(SubClass2);
        //you can write BaseClassUtil.CallFoo<SubClass2>(type2); if you want
        BaseClassUtil.CallFoo<BaseClass>(type2);
    }

    public class BaseClassUtil
    {
        public static void CallFoo<T>(Type type) where T : BaseClass
        {
            T instance = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            instance.Foo();
        }
    }
    public class TestClass
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

    }

    public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        public abstract void Foo();
    }

    public class SubClass1 : BaseClass
    {
        public override void Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SubClass 1");
        }
    }

    public class SubClass2 : BaseClass
    {
        public override void Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SubClass 2");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not sure it fits my needs. The problematic part is the "Class<T> type" part - I don't think that's valid C# syntax - and that's the whole issue. If it was, then this would definitely solve my problem. But I'm pretty sure it's not...

Comment: @milin I wrote you little example I hope this clears your doubts

Comment: I added an example what I would like to do - I feel my explanation was not clear enough because your example is concerned about generic instances, and I have a problem with generic Type instances.

Comment: @milin I don't have your method LoadFromDll, but this method should return Type. Type doesn't have generic implementation. I made your code to work.

Comment: And what does your code do if I call BaseClassUtil.CallFoo(typeof(String))? Also, I don't know of the class "SubClass2" at compile time, so I can't write "BaseClassUtil.CallFoo<SubClass2>(type2)".

Comment: @milin you will call it like this BaseClassUtil.CallFoo<string>(typeof(String)); and the compiler will give you and error: 
`The type 'string' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Program.BaseClassUtil.CallFoo<T>(Type)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'string' to 'ConsoleApplication1.Program.BaseClass'.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130415/discussion-between-milin-and-mybirthname).